# Bringing focused window to the front

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf/.net 4.6.2 application. What I need to do is to open browser (IE) in full screen mode and after that, in 5 seconds for ex, bring my application window to the top and make it focused, so that when I click on the browser (which is apparently behind) the application would appear covered

```
window.Topmost = true;
window.Topmost = false;
window.Focus();
window.Activate();
```

On Windows 7 it works perfectly, but on Windows 10 it appears as topmost but **non-focused**, and as a consequence, when I click on the browser, the application stays on top, and I have to click the application first (to give it focus) and then the browser, and only after that, browser covers the application

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I am unable to comment yet due to my low rep; however, I would like to suggest that you swap the focus and activate calls around.

```
window.Topmost = true;
window.Topmost = false;
window.Activate();
window.Focus();
```

Also, why are you setting the window topmost twice? This seems to be rather counter-intuitive as the final result would always be false.

Comment: 1st is for bringing to the front, 2nd is to prevent staying always on top. And your doesn't work as well